# jQuery variable height on multiple elements not working

Tags: jquery, variables, height, jquery-animate

I'm working on a small jQuery thingy and I'm for about 90% done (on my own i might add). But now I hit a wall since my code has gotten a bit bigger and I can't seem to find my last problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/7TRqh/ 
On this jsFiddle you can see my project.

I have 3 (or more/less) different div's that all variable in height. The buttons "meer" and "minder" make the elements slide up/down, this works all fine (allthough the code might be a bit messy).

But the problem is that it only grabs the variable height of the first element. 192px and uses that for all the elements allthough they are much heigher. So there's something wrong with the variable

```
        var currentHeight = $('.book').css('height');
            $('.book').css('height','auto');
        var animateHeight = $('.book').css('height');
            $('.book').css('height', currentHeight);
```

But I can't really seem to find the mistake, I hope someone over here can help me out with this last little problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `$('.book')` you call all the elements with the class `book`, and you will only receive the height of the first element (because you are asking for a single value: the height. It cannot return an array.

What you probably need to do is give each different `.book` element a different id, like `book1`, `book2` and `book3`. You can now get the height of each of the different `book`s.

---

EDIT:

```
$('#myID').click (function () {
  // do some expanding
  // let's get the height!
  $(this).css('height'); // this is the height of the current clicked item. 
  $(this).parent.css('height'); // this is the height of the parent of the clicked item.
}
```

You can also call this function on a group of elements, for example `$('.book .meerButton').click(function(){});`

The `$(this)` variable is really nice, if you've never seen it before, read something about it in the jQuery docs.

Comment: The thing is that everything is variable, the height is a variable but also the amount of div's is variable since it's being generated. So it's kind of hard to add the id's since that's a constant.

Isn't it possible to find the height of a certain element when clicked on it?

Comment: I looked at it with a friend and we've found the problem! The problem is that the currentHeight and animateHeight were performed before the click function so the height was allready set before anything was clicked which made all the divs have the same height.

So we moved that part into the click function but now the (simple) problem was that the function did not know what element the react to. So we put in the (this).closest to the book element so it only takes the closest book element to the button!

http://jsfiddle.net/7TRqh/3/ Here is the updated fiddle with all the problems fixed!

Answer (score 1):

$('.book') returns all elements with the book clas and height operates onyl on one element.
Toi fix this you can use the each function:

```
$('.book').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var currentHeight = $this.css('height');
  $this.css('height','auto');
  ...
});
```

Comment: I think the `var $this = $(this);` part is scary!

Comment: @Hidde What is a better way to do it? you can not call the method on 'this'? Or is it the name '$this' that scares you oO.

Comment: yeah, the name `$this` :). I usually just type `$(this)` everywhere I want to use that, instead of making a new variable for it.

Comment: @Hidde Yeah it is a good/bad habbit. If I need the result of a function call more than once I usually assign the result to a variable.